# Escape [ ] brackets in JS - trying to pass an array with a key

Tags: javascript, php, json

I'm trying to pass a php array into Javascript, this is what I have

```
var urls = <?php echo $json_array[0]; ?>;
```

However JS seems to have issues with the bracket. Maybe I'm not approaching this correctly but i know if I could get the same $json_array[0] spits out in php into my js I would be all set.

Comment: *"However JS seems to have issues with the bracket."* The browser doesn't even see the `[]` since PHP runs on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

If `$json_array[0]` contains a `String`, You are probably missing quotes:

```
var urls = '<?php echo $json_array[0]; ?>';
```